# How I can capital the first letter after number?

Tags: php

555 testing is going on

I want to make "testing" first letter caps rest will be smaller look like as below one sample

555 Testing is going on

```
$s = '555 testing is going on';
```

I want something like this one

Result = 555 Testing is going on

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You may try to use `preg_split` if you knew your string pattern or you could use `preg_replace_callback `

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are looking for something like that:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback (
    '|\d\s+([a-z])|',
    function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[0]);
    },
    "555 testing is going on 4 ever."
);
```

The regular expression matches any lowercase character following a digit followed by one or more white spaces. The match is handed over to the replacement function, the return value of that function is used as a replacement for the original match.

The output obviously is:

> 555 Testing is going on 4 Ever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to match and replace with upper case character after digits.

```
<?php
$s = '555 testing is going on 4a';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\d\s*([a-z])/',
    function($matches) {
    return str_replace($matches[1], '', $matches[0]) . strtoupper($matches[1]);
}, $s);
```

The regular expression matches digits then 0 or more spaces and the a lower case character. Hope this helps.